# Finding the sum of a finite arithmetic series where the common ratio changes

Tags: sequences-and-series

I realise how to find the sum up a finite arithmetic series when the common ratio is the same each time.

```
1/2n(2a+(n-1)d)
```

However what happens when d (the common ratio) changes each time?

EDIT: I do not want to give too many details because it is an assignment and I'm trying to understand it rather than get given the answer.

I am given the first term to be 10000. I am then told when n = 1, an amount of 54 is taken off. then for each subsequent term an amount is removed from the previous value that is 3 more. I need to find how much is left of the original 10000 after 66 terms.

Now if the difference varies I am unsure of the formula to calculate the answer. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. Even if its just to a website that details the working.

EDIT2: After the comment about the sum of the differences I tried to think of an equation to calculate the sum of a given term but couldn't do it.

```
10000-n(3(n-1)+54)+3^(n-1)
```

This worked great up until the fourth term... Sorry I'm not that good at Maths and have to work really hard to get things.

EDIT3: Another different approach. For reference there are 66 terms with term 0 being 10000.

```
1st Term = 54
Last Term = 54+3(n-1) = 54+3(66-1) = 249
```

So the sum of the accumulated negatives.

```
= 1/2 * (number of terms) * (first term + last term)
= 1/2 * 66 * (54 + 249)
= 9999
```

Therefore the amount left after 66 terms is as follows,

```
10000 - 9999 = 1
```

Any good or not?

Comment: Then it's not an arithmetic sereis.

Comment: 1) Arithmetic series gave common *differences*. Series with common ratios are called geomtric series. 2) The series you gave is neither.

Comment: Added more detail to my question. I didn't originally because I don't want to cheat

Comment: Hint: Let us concentrate on the total amount removed. If I understand the problem, the amount removed after say $5$ cycles is $54+(54+3)+(54+6)+(54+9)+(54+12)$. (I will say no more.)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not getting any closer. Please see answer

Comment: Look at @AndréNicolas comment. What are the amounts added to $54$ in each term? What kind of series do they form?

Comment: The way you have written the first equation, it could be read as $$\frac12n(2a+(n-1)d)$$ or $$\frac1{2n}(2a+(n-1)d)$$ or $$\frac1{2n(2a+(n-1)d)}$$ Formally, the first is correct, however, it may be that the third was intended. Using MathJax would help communicate the proper question.

Comment: I will have to learn how to use it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are being asked to compute

$$10000-54-57-\cdots-(51+3\cdot66)$$

Note that there are $66$ terms being subtracted:  $54=51+3\cdot1$, $57=51+3\cdot2$, etc.  So what's being subtracted from $10000$ is

$$(51+3\cdot1)+(51+3\cdot2)+\cdots+(51+3\cdot66)=51\cdot66+3(1+2+\cdots+66)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: please see original question for attempted answer. I'm sorry I'm frustratingly slow

Comment: @DiscoS2, it looks to me from your edit that you got it.

Comment: I like maths, I just don't have a gift for it. Thanks for your help.